# Return matching strings from different txt files containing lists. Each item on new line

Tags: python, string, compare

I am very new to python as well as programming in general. 
I have two text files. Each one is a list with each item on a new line.

I am trying to find matching strings, ignoring case and certain punctuation("," , "-" , "\n"), within each list. This is what I have so far:

Basically I need to translate list items and compare between 2

List1.txt

```
Proper Title Here
A Title Here, crap
B Title Here-more crap
C Title Here
D Title Here
E Title Here
```

List2.txt

```
Proper Title Here
B Title Here-more crap
Q Title List item
```

Code:

```
import re 
list1_file = open("list1.txt", "r")
list2_file = open("list2.txt", "r")

list1 = list1_file.readlines()
list2 = list2_file.readlines()

for eachlistone in list1:
    list1nosp = eachlistone.replace(" ", "")

for eachlisttwo in list2:
    list2nosp = eachlisttwo.replace(" ", "")
```

Should output:

```
Proper Title Here
B Title Here-more crap
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read in the first list and trim out unwanted punctuation

```
data = file1.read()
data = data.lower() #make it all lowercase
data = re.sub("[,-]","",data) #replace unwanted punctuation
list1= data.splitlines()
```

do the same for the second list

```
data = file2.read()
data = data.lower() #make it all lowercase
data = re.sub("[,-]","",data) #replace unwanted punctuation
list2= data.splitlines()
```

then just print the intersection of the two lists

```
print "\n".join(set(list1).intersection(list2))
```

Comment: Thank you so much I added adition re.sub for removing white space as well and it works perfectly. Appreciate your time.